# pg_routing error when generating alpha shapes

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

When running pg_routing to generate catchment areas I got this error when running the 2 queries below:

> ```
>  SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: parse error - invalid geometry
>   Hint: "se" <-- parse error at position 2 within geometry
>   Position: 26
> ```

```
select pgr_alphaShape(
 'select
 v.id::int4, st_x(v.the_geom) as x, st_y(v.the_geom) as y
 from(
 select * from pgr_drivingDistance(''select gid as id, source,
target, cost_time as cost from roadslink_fixed'', 120829, 300)
 ) as dd
 left outer join public.roadslink_fixed_vertices_pgr v on dd.node = v.id'
);

select pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
'select
 v.id::int4, st_x(v.the_geom) as x, st_y(v.the_geom) as y
 from(
 select * from pgr_drivingDistance(''select gid as id, source,
target, cost_time as cost from roadslink_fixed'', 120829, 300)
 ) as dd
 left outer join public.roadslink_fixed_vertices_pgr v on dd.node = v.id'
);
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error, I have follow different steps to build the roads in different workshops and in all I'm getting this error. Someone has have the same issue for building catchment areas?

Comment: need to pass the geom but this function is tricky. it does not always return the desired results

Comment: You could also try using https://postgis.net/docs/manual-dev/ST_AlphaShape.html which is now part of PostGIS (related issue on Github https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/issues/1603#issuecomment-1478442228 ) - they will deprecate in pgrouting from v4 onwards

Answer (score 6):

*Note that `pgr_pointsAsPolygon` has been moved to legacy as of pgRouting 3.0.0 - I won't address this function.*

---

Read the [docs](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.1/en/pgr_alphaShape.html) carefully; the full function signature

> `pgr_alphaShape(geometry, [spoon_radius]) RETURNS geometry`

**requires a `GEOMETRY` type** as it's main parameter, while you are passing in a *string literal* of a SQL query.

---

Assuming the query you are trying to pass in, you'd want to run something along the lines of this:

```
SELECT
  pgr_alphaShape(
    -- the bracketed sub-query must return a single GEOMETRY value to get accepted as parameter to pgr_alphaShape
    (
      SELECT
        ST_Collect(v.the_geom)
      FROM
        pgr_drivingDistance(
          'SELECT gid as id, source, target, cost_time AS cost FROM roadslink_fixed',
          120829,
          300
        ) AS dd
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        public.roadslink_fixed_vertices_pgr v
          ON dd.node = v.id
    ),
    <spoon_radius>
  )
;
```

---

If you need to use special/reserved characters (e.g. `"` or `'`) inside a *string* in locations where you need to pass in a *string literal* itself (*expressions*, function parameters, variable assignments in function bodies etc.), you can wrap *string literals* in `$$`, e.g.

- `SELECT $$ ' " / $$ AS string_literal;`
- or the named variant

  `SELECT $SPECIAL_CHARS$ ' " / $SPECIAL_CHARS$ AS string_literals;`

without escaping.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! it doesn't return the error but instead empty geometry collection what confused me, because up to st_collect is correct, how should I pass the collection to build a catchment area then? because anything after the alphashape doesn't work i.e. st_concavehull

Comment: does the geometry get returned if you just run the pgr_drivingDistance?

Comment: Yes it return collection until we pass it to alpha shape which results in empty